# Rust quick-xml: Deserialize random order fields

Tags: rust, xml-parsing, serde

So, I have this data

```
<Root name=”aaa”>
  <Field1>
    <Foo name=""
  </Field1>

  <Field2>
    <Bar name=""/>
  </Field2>

  <Field2>
    <Bar name=""/>
  </Field2>

  <Field1>
    <Foo name=""
  </Field1>

  <Field1>
    <Foo name=""
  </Field1>
</Root>
```

I would like to deserialize this in to something like

```
struct Root {
  name: String
  fields: Option<Vec<FieldType>>
}

enum FieldType {
  Field1(Field1Type)
  Field2(Field2Type)
}
```

Or the fields could be two separate vectors but I though it would be easier with an enum.

So this is what I have come up with:

```
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize])]
struct Root {
    name: String,

    #[serde(alias = "Field1", alias = "Field2")]
    fields: Option<Vec<FieldType>>,
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize])]
enum FieldType {
    #[serde(rename = "Field1")]
    field1(Field1),
    #[serde(rename = "Field2")]
    field1(Field2),
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize])]
struct Field1 {
    #[serde(rename = "Foo")]
    foo: String
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize])]
struct Field1 {
    #[serde(rename = "Bar")]
    bar: String
}
```

However, this gives me the quick-xml error message: `Duplicate field 'fields'`

It works if I remove one of Field1 or Field2 in the input so I guess serde/quick-xml still interprets the two as separate fields so it "expects" a new rust variable when it comes to .

Any idea on how I can make this work?

Comment: Does `#[serde(flatten)]` work on `Vec`?

Comment: `"can only flatten structs and maps"`

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by replacing: `#[serde(alias = "Field1", alias = "Field2")]` with `#[serde(rename = "$value")]`.

Although, I have no idea what it does. Maybe one day (or week) I'll spend some time trying to understand quick-xml.

Comment: [Not much](https://github.com/tafia/quick-xml#parsing-the-value-of-a-tag) to understand there. (Though I would have never thought of using it…)

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I missed that source.

Answer (score 0):

Just as an alternative answer, having two separate vecs would have also worked if you enable the `overlapped-lists` feature on your `quick-xml` dependency.

```rust
use serde::Deserialize;

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct Root {
    #[serde(rename = "@name")]
    name: String,

    #[serde(rename = "Field1")]
    fields1: Vec<Field1>,
    #[serde(rename = "Field2")]
    fields2: Vec<Field2>,
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct Foo {
    #[serde(rename = "@name")]
    name: String,
}
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct Bar {
    #[serde(rename = "@name")]
    name: String,
}
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct Field1 {
    #[serde(rename = "Foo")]
    foo: Foo,
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct Field2 {
    #[serde(rename = "Bar")]
    bar: Bar,
}

fn main() {
    let doc = r#"
<Root name="aaa">
  <Field1>
    <Foo name=""/>
  </Field1>

  <Field2>
    <Bar name=""/>
  </Field2>

  <Field2>
    <Bar name=""/>
  </Field2>

  <Field1>
    <Foo name=""/>
  </Field1>

  <Field1>
    <Foo name=""/>
  </Field1>
</Root>"#;
    dbg!(quick_xml::de::from_str::<Root>(doc)).ok();
}
```

(I also fixed the typos with double-declaring `Field1`, adjusted `Foo`/`Bar` to actually match your XML, added `@name`, and fixed a few weird pasting errors with `”` and `])]`. What's up with those…)